# Accessing props in React: Cannot read property *** of undefined

Tags: reactjs, this, state

Just getting off the ground in React. Props appear to be accessible. Seems to not like "this" in Inventory.js. What am I doing wrong?

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Inventory from './Inventory';
import ChangeForm from './ChangeForm';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.addEntryToState = this.addEntryToState.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      entries: {},
    };
  }

  addEntryToState(entry) {
    const entries = {...this.state.entries};
    const timestamp = Date.now();
    entries[`entry-${timestamp}`] = entry;
    this.setState({ entries: entries })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <ChangeForm addEntryToState={this.addEntryToState} entries={this.state.entries} />
        <Inventory entries={this.state.entries} />
        <p></p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Inventory.js

```
import React from 'react';

class Inventory extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (

      <div>
        <h2>Inventory</h2>
        <p>{this.props.entries[0].name</p>
        <p>{this.props.entries <-----*********** how to display? ****}</p>
        <p>table removed because errors</p>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Inventory;
```

ChangeForm.js

```
import React from 'react';

class ChangeForm extends React.Component {
  createEntry(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const entry = {
      name: this.name.value,
      quantity: this.quantity.value,
      size: this.size.value,
    }
    this.props.addEntryToState(entry);
    this.changeForm.reset();

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Change Form</h2>
        <form ref={(input) => this.changeForm = input} onSubmit={(e) => this.createEntry(e)}>
          <input ref={(input) => this.name = input} type="text" placeholder="name" />
          <input ref={(input) => this.quantity = input} type="text" placeholder="quantity" />
          <input ref={(input) => this.size = input} type="text" placeholder="size" />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ChangeForm;
```

Error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined Inventory.render
>   src/Inventory.js:11

```
   8 | 
   9 | <div>
  10 |   <h2>Inventory</h2>
> 11 |   <p>{this.props.entries[0].name}</p>
  12 |   <p>table removed because errors</p>
  13 | 
  14 | </div>
```

> View compiled ▶ 26 stack frames were collapsed. Object../src/index.js
>   src/index.js:7

```
   4 | import App from './App';
   5 | import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
   6 | 
>  7 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
   8 | registerServiceWorker();
   9 | 
  10 |
```

Comment: You're getting that error because `this.props.entries[0]` is undefined. Are you sure that you're setting that property to a non-empty array of objects that have a `name` property?

Comment: Did you mean to set `entries` as an *array*, not object?

Comment: I want to be able to spit out the entries object into the DOM so that I can view it as it changes on the web page, if that makes sense. How would I do that? Turn it into an array? Could there be a problem with the initial this.state = { entries: {},};

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because the `entries` prop is being set to an object, not an array. See

```
this.state = {
  entries: {},
};
```

in App.js. Entries is an object, not an array. You need to modify your code to make `entries` an array instead.

Eg:

```
this.state = {
  entries: [],
};
```

Comment: When I incorporate this change, I still get the same error in Inventory.js: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. "this" is highlighted in red.

Comment: You will still get that error if the array is empty because element 0 of an empty array is undefined. Have you made sure the array is populated? You should also be handling the empty array case.